# Postgresql constraint where child table has date and foreign key to table that has date range such that parent's date range is valid for child's date

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4. Let's say I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE parents(
    id serial not null,
    parent_daterange daterange not null,
    constraint "parent_id" primary key ("id")
);
CREATE TABLE children(
    id serial not null,
    child_date date not null,
    parent_id int4 not null references parents(id),
    constraint "child_id" primary key ("id")
);
```

I want to make sure `children.child_date` is always inside of its respective `parents.parent_daterange`.

So, this would be valid:

```
select * from children;
id | child_date | parent_id
---+------------+-----------
1  | 2016-01-01 |         1

select * from parents;
id | parent_daterange
---+------------------
1  | [2015-12-31,2016-01-10]
```

This wouldn't be valid and in this case, I'd want the INSERT statement on the `children` table to fail:

```
select * from children;
id | child_date | parent_id
---+------------+-----------
1  | 2016-01-11 |         1

select * from parents;
id | parent_daterange
---+------------------
1  | [2015-12-31,2016-01-10]
```

Comment: you should use a trigger.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/triggers.html